# Logitech K780 no longer stays connected via bluetooth Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

After scouring the web for suggestions/resolution with no success I decided to ask a new question:  I've been using my bluetooth keyboard for months with no problems until today. After getting on my laptop, pressing the F3 (which is the connection to laptop; F2 is home pc & F1 is android phone)it will not type even during the short window when bluetooth shows it's connected. Even in terminal Bluetooth will show connected: yes then shortly after, no. I am attaching a screen shot of what I believe is needed but will gladly add any other info to resolve this.

```
myviolinsings@myviolinsings-Tesseract-17-SK-R1:~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.030080] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.065187] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.714961] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[   20.434537] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   20.434552] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.434556] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.434559] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.434564] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.682870] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[   20.745130] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   20.937851] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   20.954858] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   21.682529] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   41.543255] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   41.543257] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   41.543262] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  130.538305] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  130.538308] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  130.538312] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
myviolinsings@myviolinsings-Tesseract-17-SK-R1:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:066d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Today the problem is back with BT showing K780 is connected but it willl not type. I had to reboot to even get it to stay connected. Then after a bit, it disconnects again.

dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.029966] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.065167] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.812126] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[   23.383589] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   23.383609] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   23.383612] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   23.383614] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   23.383618] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.403883] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e32
[   23.403884] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 32
[   24.584738] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   42.961545] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   42.961547] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   42.961550] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  186.820143] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  186.820148] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  186.820151] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 3301.056652] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 3301.056656] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 3303.404221] input: BM30X mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:0A5C:4503.0008/input/input39
[ 3303.404438] hid-generic 0005:0A5C:4503.0008: input,hidraw5: BLUETOOTH HID v1.29 Mouse [BM30X mouse] on 00:db:df:c2:08:d4

lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus 4 / 10
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:066d Acer, Inc
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

While I am having other issues not related here, I am wondering if a clean install would be best as I have TimeShift backups on usb flash.

Comment: Report it as a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: Report to launchpad? I am a new user, what is launchpad and how do I report it?

Comment: Run in a terminal `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the information to know how this was solved, but after reporting the bug per Pilot6 instructions, I had another issue where Discover crashed repeatedly upon trying to open it, so I reported the bug and rebooted. Note that a reboot is the 1st repair I always try in any event where things are not right, and had to restart the system after this keyboard issue arose due to my battery died and shut down the system. However, this last reboot fixed the issue.